# outlook programming with C#

Tags: outlook-addin

I am planning to do an add-ins project for Outlook 2007. I am pro developer in C#, WPF.

Please suggest books or sites for me to learn Outlook programming with C#. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Professional Outlook 2007 Programming `ISBN:9780470049945`
- Programming Applications for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 `ISBN:9780735622494`

Answer (score 0):

I am NOT an employee of this company - but I really really like Add-In Express (http://www.add-in-express.com/).

It basically lets you write WinForms style code, embed your WinForms components, deploy and update using ClickOnce (HUGE feature), supports multiple versions of Office products, no VSTO dependency or deployment necessary, easy designer, standard automation model.

To answer your question, reading their tutorials and documentation was sufficient to get started doing extensive Office/Excel/Outlook dev.

Like anything, it has its bugs, but I really like it.